# Text align in IE changes

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  text-align: left;
  color: #000810;
}
.settings-edit-table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0 15px;
}
.settings-edit-table th,
.settings-edit-table td {
  padding: 0 0 8px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 29px;
}
.settings-edit-table th {
  width: 110px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.settings-edit-table input {
  width: 388px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #808080;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 17px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="settings-edit-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Name</th>
      <td>
        <input name="firstName" id="firstName" value="test" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Surname</th>
      <td>
        <input name="lastName" id="lastName" value="test" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Phone</th>
      <td>
        <input name="phone" id="phone" value="6666666" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th scope="row">E-mail</th>
      <td>
        <input name="email" id="email" value="test@gmail.com" type="email">
      </td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

For row names text alignment is left, in Chrome, Firefox everything works fine. For some reasons in internet explorer the text align is centered. Any suggestions to fix this issue? Here is also fiddle [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/o9o0vntn/1/)

Comment: You may want to check out this discussion http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?464919-Mixing-td-and-th-in-the-same-row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add This Property

```
.settings-edit-table th{text-align:left}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 .settings-edit-table th,
 .settings-edit-table td {
    padding: 0 0 8px;
   vertical-align: top;
   line-height: 29px;
   text-align:left; //add text-align property
 }
```